# Old and New value of an Observable Object in .onChange

Tags: swiftui

I have an observable object called `MyObject` that has a published property called `property`. `property` is String.

I have this

```
.onChange(of:myObject.property, perform: { value in
}
```

the problem is that `value` contains the old value of property, when this is triggered.

Apple docs say you can capture the new and old value of properties by doing this:

```
@State private var playState: PlayState = .paused


.onChange(of: playState) { [playState] newState in
    print(playState, self.playState, newState)
}
```

I don't see how I should type the command for my case.

I have tried

```
.onChange(of:myObject.property, perform: { [myObject.property] newValue in
```

but Xcode says

> Expected 'weak', 'unowned', or no specifier in capture list

Any ideas?

Comment: It is not clear what you're going to do with those values, but I think that should be done *inside* MyObject on willSet/didSet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### **New Update Version 2.0.0**

I decided separate this 2 way, because it would make confusing of usage or using wrong code for wrong way.

Notice that you can use in this way as well, I used other way in body:

```
.performOnChange(of: model.randomElement, withKey: "WhiteRabbit") { value in
    
    print("oldValue:", value.oldValue)
    print("newValue:", value.newValue)
    print("- - - - - - -")
    
}
```

---

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject var model: Model = Model()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            
            Text(model.randomElement)
                .padding()
            
            Button("shuffle") { model.randomElement = model.array[Int.random(in: model.array.indices)] }
            
        }
        .font(Font.headline)
        .performOnChange(of: model.randomElement, withKey: "WhiteRabbit") { oldValue, newValue in  // <<: Here! using: performOnChange
            
            print("oldValue:", oldValue)
            print("newValue:", newValue)
            print("- - - - - - -")
            
        }

    }
}


class Model: ObservableObject {
    
    let array: [String] = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
    
    @Published var randomElement: String = "No random Element!"
    
}
```

---

```
extension View {
    
    func performOnChange<T: Equatable>(of inPutValue: T, withKey key: String, capturedValues: @escaping (ReturnValueType<T>) -> Void) -> some View {
        
        return self
            .preference(key: OptionalGenericPreferenceKey<T>.self, value: inPutValue)
            .onPreferenceChange(OptionalGenericPreferenceKey<T>.self) { newValue in
                
                if let unwrappedNewValue: T = newValue {
                    
                    if let unwrappedOldValue: T = backupDictionary[key] as? T { capturedValues((oldValue: unwrappedOldValue, newValue: unwrappedNewValue)) }
                    
                }
                
                backupDictionary[key] = newValue
                
            }
        
    }
    
}


typealias ReturnValueType<T: Equatable> = (oldValue: T, newValue: T)

var backupDictionary: [String: Any] = [String: Any]()

struct OptionalGenericPreferenceKey<T: Equatable>: PreferenceKey {
    
    static var defaultValue: T? { get { return nil } }
    
    static func reduce(value: inout T?, nextValue: () -> T?) { value = nextValue() }
    
}
```

Answer (score 13):

I ran into the same issue. You can capture the old value of you model property by assigning it inside the capture brackets.

```
.onChange(of:myObject.property, perform: { [oldValue = myObject.property] newValue in
  print("Old value was \(oldValue), new value is \(newValue)")   
}
```

Comment: this is a cleaner value for getting the oldValue, thank you

Comment: For me it needed to be  ```.onChange(of: categorySelection, perform: { [oldValue = categorySelection] (newValue: String?) in```

Answer (score 1):

### Version 1.0.0

Here a working example of it, notice that `onChange` would work if there is a change in value, otherwise will no react:

---

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject var model: Model = Model()
    @State private var randomElement: String = Model().randomElement
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            
            Text(model.randomElement)
                .padding()
            
            Button("shuffle") { model.randomElement = model.array[Int.random(in: model.array.indices)] }
            
        }
        .font(Font.headline)
        .onChange(of: model.randomElement) { newValue in randomElement = newValue }
        .onChange(of: randomElement) { [randomElement] newValue in
            
            print("oldValue is:", randomElement)
            print("newValue is:", newValue)
            print("- - - - - - - - - - - - ")
            
        }
        
        
    }
}
```

---

```
class Model: ObservableObject {
    
    let array: [String] = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
    
    @Published var randomElement: String = "No random Element!"
    
}
```

Comment: sorry, but like I said, in my case the property is Published by an ObservableObject class. I don't know how to do it for that case.

Comment: @Duck: New Update has been happened!

Comment: wow, looking what you did there it is completely insane. You have just blown my little SwiftUI bubble! I did not know you could declare a variable like this `Model().randomElement`... WTH!... What is going on on the first onChange?

Comment: @Duck: about ```Model().randomElement``` I just initialized the State that we need to work. I just answered the question, I can upgrade the code to higher version and better logic which does the same job without using onChange, if you need let me know, I add second update as well, per request.

Comment: @Duck: thanks, I will notice you with very advanced way of doing this soon!

Comment: @Duck: New Update has been happened!